# Split string to gather data with PHP

Tags: php, regex, split

I need to split this string into different section to gather particular data so that I can store it in a database with PHP.
I am after some help to either split or use a regex to gather this data reliably.
Not all the values will be the same length, so need a way to test for each part without just splitting based on character position.

```
Sol 1565 (Dec 31, 2016): Sunny, high -6C/21F, low -72C/-97F, pressure at 8.74 hPa, daylight 06:25-18:41
```

I want to get these separate values:

- Sol 1565 (This will always start with Sol and be followed by a 4 digit number)
- Dec 31, 2016 (The date format will always be M d, Y)
- Sunny (A word will always be used, but may not be the same word)
- -6C [high] (The high temp in C)
- 21F [high] (The high temp in F)
- -72C [low] (The low temp in C)
- -97F [low] (The low temp in F)
- 8.74 (The pressure - will be a float)
- 06:25 (daytime start)
- 18:41 (daytime finish)

Edit:
I have tried using `substr`, but soon worked out it would not be reliable. So after a solution that would be more suitable.

Comment: Regexp will do it for you.

Comment: What do you have so far, what have you tried?

Comment: @ka_lin I only tried using substr, but soon worked out it would not be reliable. My regex skills are not that great to work out for all parts of this string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to understand regex syntax then you can do easily. Here is reference: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php

I have made one to make you understand. Hope then you can do from your end.

```
<?php
$pattern = '@(high\s)([-+/0-9a-zA-Z]+)@';
$subject = 'Sol 1565 (Dec 31, 2016): Sunny, high -6C/21F, low -72C/-97F, pressure at 8.74 hPa, daylight 06:25-18:41';
$result = preg_match( $pattern, $subject , $matches );
print_r($matches);
```

And result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => high -6C/21F
    [1] => high 
    [2] => -6C/21F
)
```

You will get high value `$matches[2]`. And then you can use `explode()` to get C and F.

Just I am showing a partial solution. You can apply alternative pattern after reading regex syntax.

Comment: Thanks. With your example I managed to use some explode and regex to output the data as I need.